# How can I repeat values, count and group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a crosstab but I need a kind of query that repeat each policy_business_unit group by cia_ensures

My tables:

```
|policies|
  |id|  |client|  |policy_business_unit_id|  |cia_ensure_id|   |state|       
   1      MATT                  1                   1             0
   2      STEVE                 2                   1             0
   3      BILL                  3                   2             0
   4      LARRY                 4                   2             1

|policy_business_units|
   |id|   |name|  |comercial_area_id|
     1     LIFE         1 
     2     ROB          1
     3     SECURE       1
     4     ACCIDENT     1

|comercial_areas|
   |id|   |name|
    1      BANK
    2      HOSPITAL

|cia_ensures|
   |id|   |name|
    1      SPRINT
    2      APPLE
```

Here is the information:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4750f/2

I'm trying to get states = 0,1,2 anc count if it doesn't exist or show 0

```
Select  
  pb.name as BUSINESS_UNITS,
  ce.name as CIA,ca.name as COMERCIAL_AREAS,
  if (p.state = 0, count(p.state), 0) as state_0,
  if (p.state = 1, count(p.state), 0) as state_1,
  if (p.state = 2, count(p.state), 0) as state_2
From policies p 
  INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
  INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
  INNER JOIN cia_ensures ce ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
where ca.id=1
group by pb.id
```

I'm getting this result:

```
BUSINESS_UNITS      CIA      COMERCIAL_AREAS    STATE_0   STATE_1   STATUS_2
 LIFE            SPRINT       BANK                  1       0           0
 ROB             SPRINT       BANK                  1       0           0
 SECURE          APPLE        BANK                  1       0           0
 ACCIDENT        APPLE        BANK                  0       1           0
```

Here is my problem:

How can I do to have this result?

```
BUSINESS_UNITS      CIA      COMERCIAL_AREAS    STATE_0   STATE_1   STATUS_2
 LIFE            SPRINT       BANK                  1       0           0
 ROB             SPRINT       BANK                  1       0           0
 SECURE          SPRINT       BANK                  0       0           0
 ACCIDENT        SPRINT       BANK                  0       0           0
 LIFE            APPLE        BANK                  0       0           0
 ROB             APPLE        BANK                  0       0           0
 SECURE          APPLE        BANK                  1       0           0
 ACCIDENT        APPLE        BANK                  0       1           0
```

I tried

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN p.state = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS state_0,
   COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN p.state = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS state_1,
   COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN p.state = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS state_2,
   count(*) AS total, p.policy_business_unit_id as units,
   p.cia_ensure_id AS cias, p.state as status
   FROM policies p
   WHERE policy_business_unit_id IN (1)
   AND cia_ensure_id IN (1,2)
   GROUP BY cia_ensure_id
```

Somebody knows how to do that?

Please I will appreciate all kind of help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use subqueries and then apply a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to join them together. The `IFNULL` part at the top ensures that the filled up `NULL` values in the not existing state fields, resulting from the outer join,  are converted to 0.

```
SET @id = 1;

SELECT sections.BUSINESS_UNITS, sections.CIA, sections.AREAS,
    IFNULL(states.state_0, 0) AS STATE_0,
    IFNULL(states.state_1, 0) AS STATE_1,
    IFNULL(states.state_2, 0) AS STATE_2
    FROM (
        SELECT
            pb.id AS bus_id, pb.name AS BUSINESS_UNITS,
            ce.id AS cia_id, ce.name AS CIA,
            ca.name AS AREAS
            FROM policies p 
            INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb
            ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
            INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca
            ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
            INNER JOIN cia_ensures ce
            WHERE ca.id = @id
    ) AS sections
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            pb.id AS bus_id,
            ce.id AS cia_id,
            if (p.state = 0, 1, 0) AS state_0,
            if (p.state = 1, 1, 0) AS state_1,
            if (p.state = 2, 1, 0) AS state_2
            FROM policies p 
            INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb
            ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
            INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca
            ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
            INNER JOIN cia_ensures ce
            ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
            WHERE ca.id = @id
    ) AS states
    ON sections.bus_id = states.bus_id
    AND sections.cia_id = states.cia_id
    ORDER BY sections.cia_id;
```

DEMO @ **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4750f/34)**

Comment: @CarlitosMorales - As you can see the sql fiddle works, so it's not the query. Are your table schemata exactly the same as in your provided fiddle? And you have to replace the 3 `@id` variables with your needed values. What is the exact error message, when the crash occurs?

Comment: @CarlitosMorales - As for me, it runs without problems locally in the mysql client as well as phpmyadmin in about 0.0077 seconds. And at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4750f/34) it's working, too. Regarding to the sql fiddle, are your table schemata different in any way? If not, can you provide a bit more sample data for the tables? How much rows have your tables that you use for testing? **Have you tested with the exact same setup and data as in the fiddle? Please, check first if this works.**

Comment: @CarlitosMorales - Use the **exact same** data and schemata, please!

Comment: Yes I'm very happy but appart from that where is the sum in the query?

Comment: @CarlitosMorales - Using the same setup is important to see if the problem is in the query or somewhere else. Sum? Maybe I misunderstood the question, but I can't see a sum in your 'expected results table'. Does it work now? What was the problem?

Comment: Yes it worked and changed policy_business_unit = 1 because i have LOT OF INFORMATION and now i'm trying to get the sum =) But thanks for your help it will help.
Really appreciate your help master.

Comment: And if you want you can remove your comments